# C++: Windows Socket Error 10013

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

All of a sudden, my PC has stopped letting me bind to sockets.  It was working last night, and when I went to test a feature after a few hours of coding, nothing would bind.

Other facts:

- The same code works on my other PCs, so it's clearly something unique to my main dev machine.
- A bind to TCP port 8080 (the app has a mini-HTTP server) does work.
- Other applications I've written that listen to the same 63000-range ports also fail on this computer.

Here's some code that is failing:

```
  err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
  if(err == 0)
  {
    aSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(aSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
      SOCKADDR_IN        ReceiverAddr;
      // The IPv4 family
      ReceiverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      // Port no. 63939
      ReceiverAddr.sin_port = htons(iPort);
      // From all interface (0.0.0.0)
      ReceiverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
      err = bind(aSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ReceiverAddr, sizeof(ReceiverAddr));
      if(err == 0)
      {
```

I have tried:

- Disabling my Windows firewall (as suggested as the common fix)
- Disabling Windows Defender
- Running the app as administrator
- Rebooting
- Disabling/enabling my network drivers
- Renaming the app in question (in case the firewall was set to ban)
- Reverting to a known-good version of the app
- Trying some other known-good networking applications I've written (they also fail with 10013)
- Trying different ports in the same area
- Changing my network type from "public" to "home"

If I run `netstat`, there are no other applications using the ports I'm trying to listen on (generally TCP and UDP ports in and around the 63000 area).  Doing another quick `netstat` check, the highest local port currently bound is 53843.

Pretty sure the only app I installed last night was Kerbal Space Program, which I can't imagine has broken my net drivers.

Comment: Have you tested it on a different machine? You said that you tested another app and it also fails, so it's probably not your code. Maybe the remote machine doesn't accept your connection?

Comment: Have you considered looking up what the error code means?

Comment: EJP: The error code is WSAEACCESS [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668.aspx#WSAEACCES), which is why my initial efforts revolved around killing firewalls and antivirus.

Devolus: The same applications appear to work on my other computers.  Though I'm only listening for incoming connections, so it's not a remote-machine issue.  Outgoing connections appear to work fine, as I'm able to use the client half of my application to connect to a remote server without issues.

Comment: So I just uninstalled Kerbal Space Program and did a reboot, and now things are working.  Going to reinstall it and see if they break again, because I can't believe that it's not just a coincidence.

Comment: "the only app I installed last night was Kerbal Space Program, which I can't imagine has broken my net drivers." - there are many things in Windows world we can not imagine, but which still happen. If this was the only change in your system, then Sherlock Holmes inside telling me this is probably the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer edit: My new theory is NetBalancer, as I just uninstalled it, would have installed it around the time I started having trouble, and have had 2 days of 10013-free development since then.  Since I assume it ties its hooks fairly deep into the net stack, it makes sense too.

Will keep updating this if they come back...

Comment: Months-later update: It appears to be a network driver issue.  After a reboot, things will work fine.  But at _some point_, it'll start going into the 10013 state and I won't be able to open sockets.

Comment: Year-later update: I just uninstalled NetBalancer, which I think I would've installed around the time that I started having issues.  I've now had two days of 10013-free development, after about a week of reboots not even clearing it.

Comment: Same symptom in Python on Windows10; SysInternals.com TcpView showed me that cav.exe was going haywire binding local ports. This is part of the Pulse Secure stuff (cav = Cloud App Visibility). I stopped the Pulse Secure Service, cav.exe went away and my binds all started working. Thanks for pointing me to 3rd-party issues like this.